# Vine.co API get number of followers, likes, revines and comment

Tags: php, api, vine

Does anyone know how get number of Followers and number of Likes, Revines and Comments in http://vine.co by using PHP

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am looking to get the same, did you get anything to get number of vine followers?

Comment: try this in postman https://api.vineapp.com/users/search/badgalriri

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get those information get the code [here](https://github.com/VineAPI/VineAPI)